# getting XML request missing in XML post request using curl

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, xmlhttprequest

I need to get some data from api using post request method by sending data in xml.
here what i have done till now, but i am getting error.

```
function htlbycountry_get(){
    
        $url = "http://xmldemo.travellanda.com/xmlv1/";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $timeout = 5;
        $d = "<Request>
             <Head>
             <Username>cecd5656c336e815f69a587c69aa34cc</Username>
             <Password>3skbiOKjtaeb</Password>
             <RequestType>GetHotels</RequestType>
             </Head>
             <Body>
             <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
             </Body>
             </Request>";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/xml',
                                                   'Content-Type: application/xml'
                                                   ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($rawdata);
    
    }
```

but i am getting error in response something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Head>
    <ServerTime>2021-07-02T07:48:41</ServerTime>
    <ServerType>Test</ServerType>
    <ExecutionTime>0</ExecutionTime>
  </Head>
  <Body>
    <Error>
      <ErrorId>101</ErrorId>
      <ErrorText>XML request is missing. Use POST method to send the 'xml' parameter.</ErrorText>
    </Error>
  </Body>
</Response>
```

As per @CBroe suggestion below, i tried following but getting same error.

```
    function htlbycountry_get(){

        $url = "http://xmldemo.travellanda.com/xmlv1/";
        $timeout = 5;
        $reqdata = "<Request><Head><Username>cecd5656c336e815f69a587c69aa34cc</Username><Password>3skbiOKjtaeb</Password><RequestType>GetHotels</RequestType></Head><Body><CountryCode>GB</CountryCode></Body></Request>";
        $data = ['xml' => $reqdata];
        $headers = array(
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($rawdata);
    }
```

Comment: The error message appears to be saying that you should not send the XML as the request body, but make a normal POST request (so not `Content-Type: application/xml` either) that sends a parameter named `xml`, and with the XML data you got as the value.

Comment: Honestly, I am trying to understand your response but i am unable to make it work. can you guide a little more here. i don't understand what do you mean by normal POST here.

Comment: By “normal” I mean an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, that contains key=value pairs in the request body.

Comment: Now i get it but look at these screenshot and their documentation, i hope i am following them. https://imgur.com/C2BcBqr

Comment: and this - https://imgur.com/x8r808m

Comment: You need to send your XML code you got there as the _value_ of a parameter named `xml`.

Comment: Thanks ! let me try

Comment: @CBroe , as per your suggestion, i tried to pass xml code as value of xml parameter but still facing similar error, i have pasted the code above in question, i am sure i might be making some mistake here.

Comment: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS by default causes a `multipart/form-data` request, when an array was passed - not sure if that collides with the header you are trying to set yourself. Try and pass the result of `http_build_query($data)` instead.

Comment: @GRV: If it worked, please add an answer and make clear what the issue was. Thanks! (You can accept it after some time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cbroe, i finally made it work. here is the working code.

```
function htlbycountry_get(){
        $url = "http://xmldemo.travellanda.com/xmlv1/";
        $timeout = 20;
        $countrycode = $this->input->get('countrycode');
        $reqdata = "<Request><Head><Username>cecd5656c336e815f69a587c69aa34cc</Username><Password>3skbiOKjtaeb</Password><RequestType>GetHotels</RequestType></Head><Body><CountryCode>$countrycode</CountryCode></Body></Request>";
        $data = array('xml' => $reqdata);
        $headers = array(
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        $payload = http_build_query($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($rawdata);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        print_r($json);
    }
```